# IE 7/8 XML Rendering / XML-Viewer

Tags: xml, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, rendering

I've gone through just about every setting in IE7/IE8, and I can't seem to find it. I've googled and binged and all things between, and alas I'm here at StackOverflow to ask, what should be a simple problem:

How can I disable XML documents from being rendered into an HTML tree-structure, in IE? Is this even possible? I'd rather IE just display all the XML, without the treeview +/- buttons beside each parent node.

There must be a way!

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few ways:

- Change the file extension to `.txt`
- Add a stylesheet via a processing instruction
- Remove the file extension altogether
- Encoding the file as a base64 string, then including it as a [MHTML URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa579605) [via CSS](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets/MHTML_URIs)
- Delete msxml.dll

**References**

- [List of Microsoft XML Parser (MSXML) versions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/269238)
- [Associating Style Sheets with XML documents](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-stylesheet/)